# OCUnit: How to change the prefix of test-case methods?

Tags: ocunit, sentestingkit

Instead of the prefix `test`, I want to use `spec` because I prefer BDD vocabulary.

E.g., instead of:

```
- (void)testExample
```

I want to call it:

```
- (void)specExample
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [source code of SenTestingKit](https://github.com/jy/SenTestingKit/blob/master/NSInvocation_SenTesting.m#L51-54), I added the following file to the test target:"

```
// NSInvocation+SetTestMethodPrefix.m

@implementation NSInvocation (SetTestMethodPrefix)

+ (void)load {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setTestMethodPrefix:) withObject:@"spec"];
}

@end
```

This works, but seems like a hack, especially since `+[NSInvocation setTestMethodPrefix:]` is private.

Is there a better way to do this?